# Best way implementing AJAX Database Listener

Tags: jquery, database

based on the title above. What is the best way to implement an Ajax Database Listener.

A scenario where we want to implement a listener (e.g. if we want to retrieve the additional entries to particular table every time a new entry has been inserted).

I have tried using recursive jquery ajax post request to check the table entries. But I don't know if it is the best way. Maybe you can share something great and something best.

```
function my_table_db_listener(){        
   $.ajax({
         type   : 'post',
         url    : 'http://mysite.com/?axn=get_table_new_entries',
         success    : function(data){

                     //process data
                     ...
                     ...

                     //recursive call
                     my_table_db_listener();                  
         },
         error  : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                     alert(xhr.statusText);
         }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Long pooling also known as reverse AJAX is what you should be looking into.

Here is an [example](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: thank you sir for the answer. maybe I should do some research about long pooling. May you suggest some reference about it?